# How to convert encoded base 64 to UTF-16LE in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, utilities

Mine is an Phonegap project supporting for two platforms(Android and IOS).

For any server request I need to set the authorization header.This Header should be in encoded base64 UTF-16LE format to receive the response.

I am able to encode it to base64 by using jquery base-64 plugin.

```
var base64Enc=$.base64.encode("Surya@gmail.com"+":"+"Password01");
```

This works fine.But I need to convert this into UTF-16LE which has to be set as authorization header for my request.

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Enc);
        },
```

How can I convert base64Enc into UTF-16LE.
In java i can do the same by using `new    String(Base64.encodeBase64("Surya@gmail.com:Password01".getBytes("UTF-16LE")))`

Please help me how to do this in JavaScript/jquery.Does Jquery has any plugin to do this coversion or should I have to use any utilities to achive this.

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption that you don't have to support IE < 10, use native ECMAScript.

#### Use `window.atob()`<sup>1</sup> and `window.btoa()`<sup>2</sup>

Since:

> DOMStrings are 16-bit-encoded strings <sup>3</sup>

```
/* Base64 Encode */ 
var base64Enc = window.btoa("Surya@gmail.com"+":"+"Password01");

/* Base64 Decode (as UTF16 DOMString) */
var utf16Dec = window.atob(base64Enc);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.atob

<sup>2</sup> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.btoa

<sup>3</sup> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: Mine is an mobile app (Phonegap)which Im supporting for Android and IOS.Is this approach going to work for Mobile apps.?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. It is my understanding that Phonegap simply wraps a webview—so under the hood, it's still Javascript/HTML etc. The above approach works in Webkit which both iOS and Android's browsers run inherently.

Comment: I am able to convert into base64 by using $.base64.encode("Surya@gmail.com"+":"+"Password01")/window.btoa("Surya@gmail.com"+":"+"Password01");But I wanted this in base64 UTF-16LE format.How do i covert it into UTF-16LE ?

Comment: Yes.All of them are returning UTF8 not UTF16.:(

Comment: window.btoa("lame")  returns  "bGFtZQ==" when it should return the same as  echo -n lame|iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE |base64   which is bABhAG0AZQA=


btoa is encoding the strings as UTF8